# PHPUnit appears to pass variable by reference rather than by copy?

Tags: php, phpunit

I have the following dataprovider method:

```
public function delta_and_account_provider()
{
    $defaultAccount = json_decode(FileHelper::getJson('account.json'));
    return [
        "acceptable negative adjustment" =>
            [ -20, $defaultAccount],
        "acceptable positive adjustment" =>
            [ 20, $defaultAccount]
    ];
}
```

with the test:

```
/** 
 * @test
 * @dataProvider delta_and_account_provider 
 */
public function adjustments_modify_balance_correctly($delta, $account)
{
    $originalBalance = $account->balance;
    $expectedBalance = $originalBalance + $delta;

    $actualObject = $this->applyAdjustmentToAccount($delta,$account);

    $this->assertEquals($expectedBalance, $actualObject->balance);
}
```

The `defaultAccount` has a balance of 100, and the assertion fails on the second dataset - the balance is 100 rather than 120.

Which would mean that the variable `defaultAccount` is passed as a reference rather than by copy to the second run of the test (in the second dataset). Since in the first run I substract 20 from the 100, leaving the defaultAccount at 80, and then during the second test run it adds 20 to the 80 leaving the end result at 100, rather than 120.

The test passes if I change the dataprovider to the following:

```
public function delta_and_account_provider()
{
    $defaultAccount = json_decode(FileHelper::getJson('account.json'));
    $defaultAccount2 = json_decode(FileHelper::getJson('account.json'));
    return [
        "acceptable negative adjustment" =>
            [ -20, $defaultAccount],
        "acceptable positive adjustment" =>
            [ 20, $defaultAccount2]
    ];
}
```

The example is a bit contrived, but I want to make the point that I would expect the second test run to use a 'clean' $defaultAccount variable, provided by the dataprovider rather than the modified one from the previous test run.

Could someone please confirm this is happening for them as well? Or what is going on?

I use PHP 7.1 and phpunit 5.4

Comment: `$defaultField` no such variable within scope.

Comment: json_decode will create an stdObject by default. Objects are by default passed by reference. Have you tried setting the 2nd argument of json_decode() to true making it an array? Obviously you have to update the test to use array-notation instead of object-notation

Comment: @shudder, sorry I had a typo, fixed now - thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @dbrumann ah! I didn't know that! Interesting

Comment: @dbrumann Yep! You are right, in the function I'm testing it actually edits the parameter that is passed, which in this case is a stdClass object - seeing that it is actually passing the object by reference it modifies the actual object! Wow quite a fundamental aspect of PHP I wasn't aware of! Thank you! (if you write it up as an answer I'll happily accept it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `json_decode()` will create stdClass-object from your data. [When you pass this object as a method argument it will be passed by reference](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php), not by value. You can circumvent this by setting the 2nd argument of [json_decode](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php) to true:

```
$defaultAccount = json_decode(FileHelper::getJson('account.json'), true);
```

This will generate an associative array, which will be passed by copy.

Comment: Having read through the PHP docs you referenced, it would look like that actually the object is not passed by reference, but rather a copy of the reference. Allowing the passed argument to access the object in the same way as the original reference to it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Pass by reference and copy of reference mean the same thing to me, but I'm not a native speaker. I updated my answer to reflect the language in the documentation.

Comment: Neither am I ;) there are two comments in the PHP documentation which explain this better than I would be able to. I think the idea is that you have a reference $a which refers to the object, and when you pass $a to a method, it does not create a copy of the object, and it also does not really mean &$a is passed but rather that a copy of the reference so $a is passed to the method. So something like $b = &$a